# Java reading a file into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, java-5

How do you read the contents of a file into an `ArrayList<String>` in Java?

**Here are the file contents:**

```
cat
house
dog
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 137, accepted):

**This Java code reads in each word and puts it into the ArrayList:**

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
s.close();
```

Use `s.hasNextLine()` and `s.nextLine()` if you want to read in line by line instead of word by word.

Comment: Oh nice, shorter with `Scanner` than `BufferedReader` and no exceptions to deal with. I guess I'm used to using `BufferedReader` prior to Java 5 when `Scanner` didn't exist, although I've been using Java 5 and 6 for many years. The Commons IO library of course provides the shortest answer if available as others have mentioned, so I generally use that now.

Comment: Don't you need to specify the delimiter for the scanner, as the default delimiter matches whitespace? i.e. new Scanner(new File("filepath")).useDelimiter("\n");

Comment: @Hedley from java7 on `new Scanner(new File("filepath")).useDelimiter(System.lineSeparator())` because it can differ per OS

Answer (score 62):

You can use:

```
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(new File("input.txt").toPath(), Charset.defaultCharset() );
```

Source: [Java API 7.0](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Comment: I would use a specific Charset here instead of relying on the current platform Charset.

Comment: Also you can use `Paths.get("input.txt")` instead of `new File("input.txt").toPath(0`

Answer (score 50):

A one-liner with [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/io/):

```
List<String> lines = FileUtils.readLines(new File("/path/to/file.txt"), "utf-8");
```

The same with [guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/):

```
List<String> lines = 
     Files.readLines(new File("/path/to/file.txt"), Charset.forName("utf-8"));
```

Comment: Why not use `Charsets.UTF_8` instead of `forName`?

Answer (score 31):

Simplest form I ever found is...

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("/path/to/file.txt"));
```

Answer (score 11):

In **Java 8** you could use streams and `Files.lines`:

```
List<String> list = null;
try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(myPathToTheFile))) {
    list = lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Failed to load file.", e);
}
```

Or as a function including loading the file from the file system:

```
private List<String> loadFile() {
    List<String> list = null;
    URI uri = null;

    try {
        uri = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("example.txt").toURI();
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to load file.", e);
    }

    try (Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(uri))) {
        list = lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to load file.", e);
    }
    return list;
}
```

Comment: `List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("./input.txt")).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Answer (score 6):

```
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("words.txt"));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    words.add(line);
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: how come i can't find the size of the arraylist with "line.size()"?

Answer (score 2):

You can for example do this in this way (full code with exceptions handlig):

```
BufferedReader in = null;
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
try {   
    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("myfile.txt"));
    String str;
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        myList.add(str);
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (in != null) {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java 7+, you can use try-with-resources

Answer (score 1):

```
//CS124 HW6 Wikipedia Relation Extraction
//Alan Joyce (ajoyce)
public List<String> addWives(String fileName) {
    List<String> wives = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        // for each line
        for(String line = input.readLine(); line != null; line = input.readLine()) {
            wives.add(line);
        }
        input.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
        return null;
    }
    return wives;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that has worked pretty well for me:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(
    new Scanner(new File(file)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next().split("\\r?\\n")
);
```

If you don't want empty lines, you can also do:

```
List<String> lines = Arrays.asList(
    new Scanner(new File(file)).useDelimiter("\\Z").next().split("[\\r\\n]+")
);
```

Answer (score 1):

To share some analysis info. With a simple test how long it takes to read ~1180 lines of values.

If you need to read the data very fast, use the good old BufferedReader FileReader example. It took me ~8ms

The Scanner is much slower. Took me ~138ms

The nice Java 8 Files.lines(...) is the slowest version.  Took me ~388ms.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an entire program example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class X {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    File f = new File("D:/projects/eric/eclipseworkspace/testing2/usernames.txt");
        try{
            ArrayList<String> lines = get_arraylist_from_file(f);
            for(int x = 0; x < lines.size(); x++){
                System.out.println(lines.get(x));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("done");

    }
    public static ArrayList<String> get_arraylist_from_file(File f) 
        throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner s;
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        s = new Scanner(f);
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            list.add(s.next());
        }
        s.close();
        return list;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scr = new Scanner(new File(filePathInString));
/*Above line for scanning data from file*/

    enter code here

ArrayList<DataType> list = new ArrayList<DateType>();
/*this is a object of arraylist which in data will store after scan*/

while (scr.hasNext()){
```

list.add(scr.next());
}
/*above code is responsible for adding data in arraylist with the help of add function */

Answer (score -4):

Add this code to sort the data in text file.
`Collections.sort(list);`

Comment: Generally, answers are much more useful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do.