# How would I read only the first word of each line of a text file in java?

Tags: java, arrays, cpu-word

From a text file that contains several lines, how only the first word of each line is read and stored in an array or a list?
For example, the file is just one word per line. as below:

```
A , 5
B , 3
C , 5
D , 4
E , 3
. 
.
.
```

please help me

Comment: Literally this exact question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist

Comment: read the lines individually and then Use String.split based on whitespace character to get the first character.

Comment: thank LuxxMiner, but I want to read a word of line? how?

Comment: split each line based on a delimiter say  ,   ..as in my answer below

Answer (score 1):

//global arraylist

```
ArrayList<String> aList=new ArrayList<String>();
```

loop through the file and read each line .. as you are reading ...

```
string line = br.readLine() ....
```

// line = "A,5"

```
string []words =line.split(',');
```

// words[]= {A,5};

```
aList.add(words[0]);
```

Or simple

```
aList.add(br.readLine.split(',')[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am here to help you on adding that into an ArrayLists. I know I am a little late, but I'll give you my best. 
I would recommend creating a private String ArrayList class up above. So like

```
private ArrayLists<String> first;
```

Start off by reading the line of the file by using a Scanner. Like this:

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(Name of the File);
```

By the way, I'm assuming you created a name for that file so the scanner can read it.

Next, you have that Scanner read each line of that file like this.

```
while(console.hasNextLine()) {
```

and inside of it, you create a String for that Scanner like this

```
        String z = console.nextLine();
```

and then you create a String Array inside and have it split by whatever you have in between, in your case, it's a Space. so like this.

```
String [] zip = z.split(" ")
```

Then, you add whatever is in that zip, with the first index which is zero. And there you have it.

```
first.add(zip[0]);

        }
    }
```

Sorry it's a little messy, Let me clear it up now.

```
 private ArrayLists<String> first; 
 Scanner console = new Scanner(Name of the File);
 while(console.hasNextLine()) 
 {
 String z = console.nextLine();
 String [] zip = z.split(" ")
 first.add(zip[0]);

     }
 }
```

Let me know if anything is flawed here. I tried my best.