# Making a List in Java from a text file

Tags: java, list, file, java.util.scanner

In Java I'm using the `Scanner` to read from a text file, 
for example (cat, dog, mouse).
When I use the `System.out.println()` the output appears like `cat, dog, mouse`

I want the list to look like this

```
cat
dog
mouse
```

any help code below

```
    Scanner scan = null;
    Scanner scan2 = null;
    boolean same = true;
    try {
        scan = new Scanner(new      
        File("//home//mearts//keywords.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    List<String> firstLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (scan.hasNextLine()) {
    firstLines.add(scan.nextLine());
    System.out.println(firstLines);
}
```

Comment: Can't you use a for loop?

Comment: There is a similar answer here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
firstLines.forEach(System.out::println);
```

By the way, as you are only reading lines, you may also want to have a look at [java.nio.file.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html):

```
Path keywordsFilepath = Paths.get(/* your path */...);
Files.lines(keywordsFilepath)
     .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are reading the file line by line, instead of taking the delimiters into consideration:

```
try (Scanner scan = 
     new Scanner("//home//mearts//keywords.txt").useDelimiter(", ")) {
    while (scan.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(scan.next());
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace(); // Or something more useful
}
```