# Java adding file contents to array list

Tags: java

Hi i am new to Java working with files. I have got a text file called `banking.txt` located in `C:` but when i try put its content into an `ArrayList` and print it prints out nothing. Is the file path i am using incorrect or is it something different?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class FileP {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(new File("C:\\banking.txt"));
        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(read.hasNextLine()) {
            myList.add(read.nextLine());
        }
        System.out.println(myList);
    }
}
```

Comment: "it prints out nothing": this is hard to believe. Which output do you get exactly?

Comment: It prints out this with no elements inside " { } "

Comment: There is a small possibility that program is not able to read file in C: directory. Try to run your code with administrative rights. (If using cmd then run cmd as admin or using any IDE then run IDE as admin) <OR> try again by changing path from C: drive to D: drive.

Comment: This should be work.
may be permission issue. any output?

Comment: Related: [Java reading a file into an ArrayList?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5343689) Although not voting to close as duplicate because your code should be working or throwing an exception (not getting anything in the list should mean the file is empty).

Comment: Just trying to find the run as admin button in intelliJ! haha

Comment: Are you sure your filepath is correct?

Comment: @Blue close IntelliJ and re-run as admin (option By right clicking on IntelliJ app icon)

Comment: You could check whether your file 1) exists and 2) can be read. Check this example : https://ideone.com/7NckQf

Comment: Using the code from @MacDaddy answer it works which is odd because ye were saying that my code was correct, so now we know the path is correct. Running as admin now

Comment: Running as admin gives the same output

Comment: @DiabloSteve answer solved the problem but thank ye for yer help!

Comment: I can reproduce this by trying both `File` and `FileReader` in the Scanner constructor trying to read the same system file (on Win 7) - one prints an empty ArrayList, the other prints the file contents. There might be some permissions differences between the two, but I can't tell you what the exact problem is.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. It just works. Always. With both File and FileReader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to use this code as the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:\\banking.txt"));
```

This will read the file as a String and you can add it to Array.
Check this post for more:
[Reading a plain text file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java)

Comment: Why would this fixed the problem? Scanner has a constructor that takes a File.

Comment: I am unsure but with this modification made to my code it is all printed out.

Comment: can you try again with your previous code. because it also have to work.

Comment: I already tried it, i undid all the changes and { } is printed then i switched back again to this code and it prints it correctly i even switched to netbeans and the very same thing.

Comment: Dukeling. Check these 2 links to know what is the different between "new File()" and "new FileReader()".
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/io/FileReader.html

Answer (score 2):

Try to use InputStream

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;

    public class FileP {

      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("C:\\banking.txt");
        BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = buf.readLine();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (line != null)

        {
          myList.add(line);
          line = buf.readLine();
        }

       System.out.println("myList : " + myList);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This works but as others have said the way i did should work too.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the lines method of Java 8:

```
 Stream<String> content = Files.lines("C:\\banking.txt")
 content.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Same comment as for CodeMatrix : good suggestion, but no obvious reason why it would fix OP's problem.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, the proper way is: `try (Stream<String> content = Files.lines("C:\\banking.txt")) { content.forEach(System.out::println); }`. This ensures the file gets closed after finishing.