# Read a .txt file into ArrayList line by line

Tags: java, android, arraylist, java.util.scanner, indexoutofboundsexception

In my latest project i use a .txt file called *"**atestfile.txt**"* which resides inside my projects /raw folder, which i created:

[image: location of file]

and this is its content:

[image: file content]

now using these few simple lines of code..

[image: code]

i want my application to **insert the words from the textfile into my ArrayList** line by line as seen in [this questions awesome first answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist)

However, no Toast will appear, and even worse, **i will receive an IndexOutOfBoundsException** for the *test.get(3);* line i use and the application crashes.

I tried all day to get rid of this error but have not succeeded yet in doing so.
So since there are a lot of smart people around here and i'd love to learn something about this problem, i thought i'd ask you guys for help first before throwing my computer out of the window.

I'll provide you guys with my error message, copy & pasteable code aswell as my packet structure for some more help on this issue.

```
package com.niklas.cp.citypopulation;
```

[image: huge error message]

```
   final ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("android.resource:// com.niklas.cp.citypopulation/raw/atestfile.txt"));

        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){


            makeToast(scanner.nextLine(),1);
            test.add(scanner.nextLine());

        }
        scanner.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String abc = test.get(3);
    tv_highscore.setText(abc);
```

Comment: Don't put text in as images.  Please post the actual text here.

Comment: Also your stacktrace indicates the test array has a length of 0 but you are expecting it to contain your text file values, so maybe there not being input correctly

Comment: please do not use images. Your bug is in `new File("android.resource:// com.niklas.cp.citypo...`. There is a space there after `/`. This is causing an exception before the exception that you posted.

Comment: @SherifelKhatib Hey, i'll make sure not to use any images in any of my next questions. And good catch, i corrected the space after the `/`, unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @NiklasDaute You should also edit this question and replace the images. You can use the **edit** link below your question in order to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling scanner.nextLine() twice in each loop, but only adding second line to `test`, thus `test` will have only three lines.
You have to write like this

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
   String s = scanner.nextLine();
   makeToast(s,1);
   test.add(s);
}
```

If it throws FileNotFoundException try the following

```
InputStream file = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.atestfile);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
```

Comment: Hey, the InputStream was the solution to my problem.. thanks!