# How to add content of the file to an array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have used `BufferedReader` to read the content from the file but now I want to store the content of the file into an array list where my file contains some text from the pdf so now I wanted to add all those content to the array list

Here I have created array list but now I don't know how to proceed how to go next and then read from while loop so please help me

```
        ArrayList<String>YourList=new ArrayList<String>();
        FileReader fr = new 
        FileReader("D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String s;

        String keyword = arra.get(6);

        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if (s.contains(keyword)) {
                s = s.replaceAll(keyword, " ");
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
```

Comment: do you want to add lines to an array list only with `keyword` ?

Comment: check this out, I think it will help you. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist)

Comment: See I want to add That file Reader into an array list

Answer (score 1):

If you can use java8, there is `Files.lines` method:

```
String keyword = arra.get(6);
List<String> list = Files.lines(Paths.get(PATH_TO_FILE))   // returns stream of lines from source file
            .filter(s -> s.contains(keyword))   // filter by keyword
            .collect(Collectors.toList());      // add filtered lines to list
```

list will contain all lines from source file that has `keyword`

Comment: It says cannot find symbol method of  (cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method of(String)
  location: interface Path)

Comment: I have used but it is giving same error and i am using java 8

Comment: @Deo sorry.. method `of` is from java11. Use `Paths.get` instead. Answer updated

Comment: It's giving a same error it suggesting me class after   '.'

Comment: @Ruslan sometimes I wonder if we should just stick to the latest Java relase. What's the point in sticking with Java 8 examples?  And sometimes I wonder how we should phrase answers to make them "understandable"...

Comment: @ Ruslan after using get I am getting error   cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method get(String)
  location: interface Path

Comment: @ Ruslan it is not adding any content present in the file

Comment: Has I said in my problem statement that I have to add the content which is been there in the text file to an array list and then I have to fetch that word in that array list

Comment: Yes Keywords are present in the text file

Comment: @Deo so.. try to comment `filter` line and see what the array list will contain

Comment: how to reuse that lamba @Ruslan??

Comment: Because i have to use that keyword in database block so it's giving me an error that lamba must be declared either final or effectively final

Comment: @Deo right, you can't reassign the variable that is used in lambda expression. So in your case you can pass keyword directly like `.filter(s -> s.contains(arra.get(6)))`

Comment: I'm not sure what database part you mean..You can see more about effectively final https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34865383/variable-used-in-lambda-expression-should-be-final-or-effectively-final

Comment: k but I want to replace the keyword part now so can you help me

Comment: I want only the text extracted from that pdf part so i tried like this but it is saying that s in not defined   String keyword = null;
           List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
           
            Files.lines(Paths.get("D:\\PDFTOEXCEL\\Extractionfrompdf.txt")) // returns stream of lines from source file
                    .filter(s-> s.contains(arra.get(6)))
                 
                    .forEach(list::add);
           keyword.replaceFirst(s," ");
            System.out.println(list);

Comment: `s` is defined within lambda (inside `filter` method only). You can't use it outside of it. Why do you need `replaceFirst` ?

Comment: I want only text which is been identified from that text file i.e :[Compte de facturation : 9355941544] my ouput is like this so now i want only right part not COmpte de......

Comment: @Deo so i reccomend you to ask a new question. Describe what you are expecting and what do you have for now and post it