# how to import a text file in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have an assignment from my teacher i have make a serial program into a parallel with OMP.It's the Barnes-Hut one and its the first time i'm using netbeans.
I have a text file with someone numbers and i gotta import it into the project so it can use the values the text file has.How can i import the example.txt into netbeans?
I've tried this but it doesn't work
`File myFile = new File("example.txt");`
It also contains a scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // for reading from stdin
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: I've reread this a few times, and it's still not entirely clear to me wether this is a question about adding a file to a NetBeans project, or file IO in Java.

Comment: @Dimittris gs We suggest you look at this link and read the comment by Lars it deals with speed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343689/java-reading-a-file-into-an-arraylist we loaded a 650,000 word txt file in 70 ms and with a scanner it took 560 ms

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your text file is in the classpath

Comment: I tried but still it says Run and its stuck at 50% and doesn't seem to do anything

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of choices.

## 1. Relative Path

You can use a relative path.  This means you take your current "working" location and look for the file from there, this is basically what you're doing now.

The problem with this is, the "working" location changes, and is based on the location from which the program is executed.  Remember, the location of the class is not the same as the "working" location.

Netbeans "default" "working" location is usually the root directory of the project.  There are ways you can configure Netbeans to use a specific "working" location, but you need to consider what happens when you're no longer running in Netbeans.

So a "simple" solution would be too drop the file into the Netbeans project directory.  A slightly more advance solution would be to configure the project's "working" directory to a location containing the file

## 2. Absolute Path

This is when you use a fully qualified path from the a root location to the file (ie `C:\some\place`).

The problem with this is, rarely are this paths the same from one computer system to another and you need to remember to place the file into this location each time.

### 2.1 A "well known" location

A form of the absolute path solution is to place the file into a "well known" location, typically based on the OS.

For example, on Windows, you would typically use something like `{user.home}\AppData\Remote\{name of your application}`.

This would allow you to place the file in, what is essentially a "static" location and load it when ever you needed to.

But, this is probably over kill for your needs

## 3 Embedded resource

A more common solution is to "embed" the resource with your application.  Essentially, this is placing the file within the applications class path, which allows the Java runtime to locate it.

In Netbeans, this means putting the file within the `src` directory, preferably in a subdirectory, like `resources` for example.

Then, when you want to read the file, you'd need to use [`Class#getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [`Class#getResourceAsStream(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) to gain access to it.

So, based on the available information, and the example above, you might do something like...

```
try (InputStream is = YourClass.getResourceAsStream("/resources/example.txt")) {
    // Read the file...
} catch (IOException exp) {
    // Handle the exception
}
```

Just remember, this renders the resource "read-only" (at least for context of this simple example)