# project can read txt files in IDE, but isn't working after exporting project

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I just finished a little game and now I want to export it, so that I can use it as a normal application, which I can start from my desktop. It is working, but when it tries to read the .txt files, where I want to save a few important things, it isn't working anymore. But in the IDE it is working. I tested it with Eclipse and IntelliJ, but I get the same result.

[image: programm structure]

That's how I tried to save all of the things. the pictures are in folders in the res folder, which is in the src folder. this is working fine. I tried the same thing with the file in the saves folder, which also is in the src folder, but they aren't working after export.

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getClass().getResource("/res/player/" + name + "/data.txt").getFile()));
```

That's the code with that I tried to read the text files

I didn't find any videos or other information in the internet, how to solve this problem.

Comment: A "embedded resource" can not be treated like a file, instead you need to use the resulting `URL` directly to read the resource

Comment: @MadProgrammer oh wow, it is working perfect, that was the first time I was using stack overflow, I think, I am going to use it more now, that was really helpful. Thanks

Comment: This is a rather common issue, but unless you understand what it is, it's not easy to find a solution to.  Glad we could help

Answer (score -1):

You can try to pass the full length path to your BufferedReader.

Out of the blue:

```
String path = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
```

Then build your location from there.
If that does not work, have a look here:

```
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file][1]
```

Then just try

```
BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(NewFileInputStream( [path] ) );
```

Oh, and also, it maybe faster for you to look directly into the api instead of searching for videos and tutorials. Those tend to run for half a hour and in the end you wasted your time when you in reality only needed 1 line of code.

```
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html
```

Answer (score -1):

> the pictures are in folders in the res folder, wich is in the src folder.

This suggests that when you "export" the project, the contents of the `res` folder is been bundled into the resulting Jar.

This is an approach commonly known as "embedded resources", where the resources are "embedded" into the application/Jar.

Since a Jar is just a zip file, you won't be able to access these resources as if they were files on the disk, because they aren't.

Instead, you'll need to make use of the resulting `URL` directly or use `Class#getResourceAsStream`, depending on your needs.

This means, that instead of...

```
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getClass().getResource("/res/player/" + name + "/data.txt").getFile()));
```

you should be using something more like...

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/res/player/" + name + "/data.txt")));
```

I also hope you're making use of [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to manage you resources

Also, note, that embedding resources like this makes them readonly.

Comment: does that mean, I cant write text into the files anymore? where should I save them otherwise

Comment: Okay, that's a much more complicate question. For [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53405312/java-reading-the-properties-file-outside-of-jar-file/53405540#53405540), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58963290/how-to-import-a-text-file-in-netbeans/58963661#58963661), [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53974191/get-current-path-of-executed-file/53982349#53982349)

Comment: Essentially, each OS has a concept of "application support", where applications can easily write data to, typically based on the current user.  This makes the location "stable" and relatively easy to access and avoids many of the security pit falls OS's are now applying

Comment: so should I let the programm create the folders and text files, once it is startet the first time on the computer and then I can save them in the AppData Folder, because the User cant delete ore change it on accident?

Comment: Ahh, that's a decision you need to make.  You could "extract" the resources you've embedded and store them in a "well known location" or, if it doesn't matter, create them when the program is first started, which you choose will be dependent on what you want to achieve

Comment: ok, thanks. I think I now have an idea what I have to do

Comment:  Would any one care to highlight th issue with the answer and in what ways it doens't answer the user's question or would otherwise be a bad recommendation?

Comment: what haha, what do you mean

Comment: The answer was downvoted by some one and I'm curious to know why and how it might be improved